# Python dataframe data is not matching with SQL query result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-redshift

We are running the script at busy time around `7` AM which connects to RedShift using select query

1. When we export the dataframe to csv, and compare the data. We found that the field `field10_No` has mismatch value e.g. some SQL entry value of `-29` whereas the pandas dataframe has value of `-28`. However, the rest is fine
2. Sometime the number of records from Pandas have less records than that from SQL query e.g. SQL Redshift returns `4608` records and dataframe gives `3120` records

Now when we run the same code at `8` AM, it gives proper result, matching all record count and field data. So we still confuse on why at specific time pandas dataframe did not match the SQL query result on the server

```py
query = '''SELECT  field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7_No,field8_No,
field9_date,field10_No,field1_number 
FROM schema.TableName 
;''' 

data = Redshift_connection(query)
noforecords = len(data.index)
print('noforecords :' +str(noforecords))`
```

Let us know in case any suggestions or references

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume the database is changing during this window - updates and such.  The results of a query are based on the state of the database when the transaction was started, which can be very different than when the query is run.  Is either of sessions long-lived?  Can you check the transaction start times for each query?

Comment: Hi Bill,

Thanks we are investigating it.

When we run the query from DBViewer, it shows correct data but only when we are loading into dataframe from Panda it's not matching.

Plus there is a Dotnet program that connects to redshift same time and it also get's correct data. That program is connecting from Japan server and our RedShift  on Singapore.

So we are wondering why dataframe don't get same result when we are in same region whereas Dotnet is connecting from another region.

Comment: This sure sounds like Panda is running with a stale transaction.  If you can find the query issued by Panda and look up the transaction id (xid) in svv_transaction, you can see when the transaction was started.  Once a transaction starts Redshift delivers unchanging data.  If a transaction lasts a long time it can be seeing old data.